# Skip empty fields when adding a new record using vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have a form that users open to add new fees and services for clients. There are 10 fields for fees and I have it setup to auto-populate the fee verbiage if the user un-checks a "standard hourly rate" check box.

If they un-click Std-Hourly, then the field [Fee001] will go from being greyed out and blank, to display "Services # 1 through # 3...." and the user can edit the text if they need it to show "Services # 1 through #7" (depending on how many services the client has)

When the user clicks the Save button, I have the data then saved to TblFee_ByClient table. The table has a record for each service ([ClientID] and [Service] are the only 2 fields in this table) but the form itself has 10 fields ([Fee001], [Fee002], Fee003] and so on) that the user can edit/generate.

All works except my code also adds records for the fields that the user clears/deletes so that I have a record with [ClientID] and no service listed. How do I add code to skip fields that are empty? Here is the vba so far and I am getting an error "Argument not optional" on the "Move.Next":

---

```
Private Sub Toggle154_Click()

Dim TblFee_ByClient As DAO.Recordset
Set TblFee_ByClient = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [TblFee_ByClient]")

    TblFee_ByClient.AddNew
        
    TblFee_ByClient![ClientID] = Me.ClientID.Value
        If Me.Fee001.Value Is Not Null Then
    TblFee_ByClient![Fee] = Me.Fee001.Value
        Else Move.Next
        End If
        
    TblFee_ByClient![ClientID] = Me.ClientID.Value
    TblFee_ByClient![Fee] = Me.Fee002.Value

TblFee_ByClient.Update
TblFee_ByClient.Close

Set TblFee_ByClient = Nothing


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is `TblFee_ByClient.MoveNext` but don't see it's needed here.
Use IsNull() in VBA. `Is Null` is for queries. Or better, handle possibility of Null or empty string.
Don't open recordset with existing records.
Need a conditional statement for each of the 10 controls. This can be accomplished in a loop.

```
Private Sub Toggle154_Click()

Dim TblFee_ByClient As DAO.Recordset
Dim x As Integer, strFee As String

Set TblFee_ByClient = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [TblFee_ByClient] WHERE 1=0")
With TblFee_ByClient
For x = 1 To 10
    strFee = "Fee" & Format(x, "000")
    If Nz(Me(strFee), "") <> "" Then
        .AddNew
        !ClientID = Me.ClientID
        !Fee = Me(strFee)
        .Update
    End If
Next
.Close
End With
Set TblFee_ByClient = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: The fields [Fee001], etc on the Form are actually Long Text fields.

Comment: Generally, this code doesn't care what data type fields are. strFee is variable for name of form controls.